# Not getting the AuthenticationException from spring security

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, authorization, bearer-token

I am using token based authentication and authorization in my code.

I am trying to handle the AccessDeniedException and AuthenticationException.
But spring silently return the 401 code to user in case if I pass in correct token.

Below is my code :

```
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests(requests -> requests
                    .antMatchers("/xyz/*")
                    .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated())
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .jwt()
            .jwtAuthenticationConverter(new AadJwtBearerTokenAuthenticationConverter());


    //register for all error authentication related error handling
    http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint);


}
```

My authentication entry point code is below. Commence method doesnot get invoked :

```
@Component
public class AuthEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("handlerExceptionResolver")
    private HandlerExceptionResolver resolver;

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("************** exception  "+authException);
        authException.printStackTrace();
        resolver.resolveException(request, response, null, authException);
    }
}
```

Now, I am able to get the AccessDeniedException when I dont pass any token, but if I pass incorrect token, the authentication exception is not thrown, and spring returns 401 response to user without any exception.

What am I missing here?

Comment: could you please add your `authEntryPoint` code?